# Printing the number of digits of an integer

Tags: c

I have to submit this code, the intention is to count the digits of a number and print it (range is from -2<sup>31</sup>+1 to 2<sup>31</sup>-1) and the result must be presented as a single number (for example, given the number 234 it prints 3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long int num_ins;
    int contador = 0;

    printf("Inserir numero desejado a avaliar?\n"); // asking the number
    scanf("%ld", &num_ins);

    if (num_ins == 0) {
        printf("%d", 1);
    } else {
        while (num_ins != 0) {
            num_ins = num_ins / 10;
            contador++;
        }
        printf("%d", contador); //contador is count
    }
}
```

But the submission keeps giving me an error, that there are some numbers where it isn't right, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: `"%lu"` is for an unsigned long. Use `"%ld"` for a signed long.

Comment: Could it be, perhaps, that the program is supposed to calculate the result for more than one input?  And that maybe it also expects the output to have line-endings?

Comment: On my side, it does work. Just compiled it to test. You should check what your submission says. It might be giving the number as parameter, instead of STDIN; or might want you to return it instead of output it ... That's my best guess, because the code should work for those numbers.

Comment: *But the submission keep giving me an error*  What **specifically** is the error?  What is your input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Indent your code properly next time, please.

Comment: Did you test your code with simple inputs? Like 0, 1, 9, 10, **-1, -9, -10**?

Comment: I suggest that you use cast: ```num_ins = (long) num_ins / 10;``` Because the result is a float

Comment: @Mulli No, it's not.  Division between two integers is an integer.

Comment: Well, [for some relaxed definition of "work"](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P9WGIu2sk4hPW5yA). When the wrong format specifier is used, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @user3386109 actually i had corrected id before i copied to here(forgot to update that part)

Comment: @paddy nop, only 1 number by time

Comment: @the error is in the output(in a test automatic created not by me), the answear do nto coincide

Comment: @swordfish sorry buddy

Comment: @mkrieger tried that and a shitload of them xD 0 gave me a error at first, but fixed it in that last code

Comment: In any case, I'd suggest also to add a newline at the end of your print statements: `printf("%d\n", contador);`

Comment: @leNiglo tried return, and nop xD

Comment: Are you supposed to count the - sign on negative numbers? Do you have to exclude -2^31 that can be coded in the long value? Are your longs actually on 32 bits?

Comment: It sounds like you're using an online judge site, and usually those do not want any prompts like your first `printf` to appear in the output.

Comment: Note `if (num_ins == 0) {
        printf("%d", 1);
    }
    else` is not needed.  Instead `do {
            num_ins /= 10;
            contador++;
        } while (num_ins);`

Comment: "count the digits of a number" or  "count the characters of a number"?  What should `-123` report?  What should `xyz` report? 0?  (try `long int num_ins = 0;`)

Comment: You should post a pointer to the actual online submission site. If not possible, post the problem description from the site.

Comment: most of the online coding has the first item passed to the program is a counter of how many data items will be passed to the program.  With out the actual link or the actual text, we really cannot help you much

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using a 32 bit data type, then the range will be `-2^31 to 2^31 -1`.

So the maximum positive number will be `2^31 = 2147483647` and minimum will be `-2147483648`

`long int` is sometimes 64 bits (as is on my PC) so its range will change. Max value will then be `9223372036854775807`

According to your code,

- If input is `2147483647`, then output = `10`. (Correct).
- If input is `9223372036854775807` (max valid value) , then output =
  `19` (Correct).
- If input is `92233720368547758078`(exceeds max valid value and has number of digits as 20) , then
  output = `19` (Incorrect).